# Installing Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit .android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded

Tags: android-studio, java-8, ubuntu-14.04

When i'm installing Android Studio 2.1 It shows me error

```
./studio.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@28c97a5 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/usr/local/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/kedinn/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna--1135288993/jna5651086287161650628.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/kedinn/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna--1135288993/jna5651086287161650628.tmp
[  11587]   WARN - oidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider - File /home/kedinn/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  22630]   WARN - ome.install.ComponentInstaller - File /home/kedinn/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
```

I don't understand if the warning is a important, because the installation is running
Help me please

Answer (score 19):

Android Studio will run fine without it, but if the warning concerns you, you can create the file  ~/.android/repositories.cfg with the following content and the warning will not appear again.

```
### User Sources for Android SDK Manager
count=0
```