# Android Studio 2.3.3 stucks when first run

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I downloaded [Android Studio 2.3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) for `Linux` and unzipped the content to `/usr/local`
then

```
$ cd android-studio/bin
```

Edited the file `idea.properties` and appended a following line to it:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Then launched Android Studio:

```
$ sudo sh studio.sh

Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@1a7cec2 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/usr/local/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /root/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/tmp/jna5562911082428971611.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /root/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/tmp/jna5562911082428971611.tmp
[  40066]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
^C[18124266]   WARN - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 130
```

And it will stuck. After long waiting I termited it with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

Comment: Are your running as root?

Comment: @fhossfel With root the result is the same.

Comment: Non, you should not run as root. But I find it odd that it tries to access /root/.android/repositories.cfg

Comment: I think the corresponding repository are not available at the path

Comment: remove this line `disable.android.first.run=true`

Comment: @UpendraShah The result is the same.

Comment: @xralf Why you edited idea.properties??

Comment: @UpendraShah I googled similar problem and in that case this helped.

Comment: Why do you run studio as root?? Don't do it. No need to install as root, and not run as root

Comment: I think my answer below will fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all your problems happen because you ran as `root` (`sudo`) on your first run.

So try to **unroot** before doing a clean install like I suggest below:

### Unroot the installation

1. `cd` to the folder where you unzipped *Android Studio* before
2. `cd ..`
3. Recursively change user and group:

   ```
   sudo find <thedirname> -print0 | xargs -0 chown <yourusername>:<yourgroupname>
   ```
4. `cd ~` or `cd` to go back to home
5. Recursively change user and group

   ```
   sudo find .Android* -print0 | xargs -0 chown <yourusername>:<yourgroupname>
   ```

   (I `sudo` because you've used `root` user previously).
6. Recursively change user and group

   ```
   sudo find Android* -print0 | xargs -0 chown <yourusername>:<yourgroupname>
   ```
7. `cd` into the unzipped directory. Do `chmod +x studio.sh`.
8. Start *Android Studio* `./studio.sh`

If it didn't help, do a:

### Clean install

1. Download and unzip a fresh copy of *Android Studio*. I suggest [version 3](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html), it's pre released, but stable. It doesn't matter where you put it.
2. I believe you have *Java* installed, but make sure you have `Java 8` as the default one: in command line: `java -version`, make sure it's `1.8`.
3. Move any old installations out of the way, in case they are corrupt:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/.Android* ~/tmp/
   sudo mv ~/Android ~/tmp/
   ```

   should do the trick. (I `sudo` because you've used `root` user previously).
4. `cd` into the unzipped directory. Do `chmod +x studio.sh`.
5. Start *Android Studio* `./studio.sh`

Make sure all the files are owned by your `username`, and group as well.

Comment: Yesterday, I tried the first sequence of steps of your answer, but ended it after ten minutes because lack of time and tried the second sequence of steps. I'm back here today and it worked. So, the second sequence certainly works. Thank you for such a precise, complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try attaching to the process with `strace` to see what it's doing (for example, waiting on a network or file). Or run it with `strace` like this:

```
strace -o foo.log -s1024 -f ./studio.sh
```

After a while, break it with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and examine the log file for syscalls like **open**, **read**, **recvmsg**.

Alternatively, while it's running, you can attach with a *Java profiler* to the **jvm**. For a start, you can launch `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` and attach to the *Android Studio* (it will show as an empty name, with only PID) and view stack traces of individual threads. In `jvisualvm` you can view the CPU usage sample and click on the hot event and see the stack trace.

Basically you need to find out what the app is trying to access for so long. Most likely some network resource.

Comment: I did `strace` and it's full of syscalls like "open, "read", "recvmgs".

Comment: Could you please describe the instructions for jconsole or jvisualvm in more specific steps? (I don't have experience with these tools).

Comment: @xralf have you looked for errors in the strace log, especially for calls like open/socket/read? Do you see what files or network resources it tries to access?

Comment: @xralf For jvisualvm, just run the command (you might need to install the "visualvm" package), then double-click the "Android Studio", go to "Sampler" -> "CPU" and look at the top entries in the table. You can press "Thread dump" to see stack traces.

Comment: I have also noticed you run with "sudo". Does running as a non-root without "sudo" work? Do other apps such as "gedit" run with "sudo"? If not, run "xhost +" as your default non-root user from terminal.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I noticed only one of them before, because a lot of activity on this question. auval solved it, but every answer is useful here.

Answer (score 2):

I took some information from:

- [Stuck at “.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433542/stuck-at-android-repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded)
- [Installing Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit .android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448482/installing-android-studio-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-android-repositories-cfg-could)

**The answers collectively say that:**

> Android Studio will run fine without `repositories.cfg`.

You can remove this warning by putting the following into `repositories.cfg`:

```
### User Sources for Android SDK Manager
count=0
```

> After waiting some time it eventually goes beyond that step.
>
> Patience is the key.

So, try waiting a little bit more. It always helps.

Comment: What is little bit more? (e.g. in minutes)

Comment: I don't know, but gradle is famous for its slowness.

Comment: I terminated it after 18 hours.

Comment: @xralf _**wow.**_ Gradle is slow, but I did not know that it is **so slow**.

Comment: I use 2 GB of RAM on my laptop, but hope this is not the cause.

Comment: It might not be the cause but it would be the cause of lots of headaches afterwards. My laptop had 4GB of RAM and a 2.5GHz processor and it took me hours to be able to write a few lines of code, and let's forget about the emulation...

Comment: @Shinratensei And are you on Linux? I would like to get familiar with the Android Studio and use it for GUI (layouts) and for code primarily vim editor.

Comment: No, sorry, I use it on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

This is common. On your first run the gradle files are needed to be downloaded and installed in background. It's about 90 MB in size and even if your internet speed is high, the gradle servers may be slow taking it to maximum of 1 or 2 hours in the worst case. So open Android Studio and wait until it opens. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, I'll let it running. I didn't have an idea that this could take so long without giving a response to the user, what is happening.

Comment: No, after two hours it's still running.

Comment: Now, it's about 18 hours, so I terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a potientaly useful link from AskUbuntu, the guy suggested creating an empty file called repositories.cfg. And that solved it.

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/885658/android-sdk-repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded

Comment: Maybe on a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `/root/.AndroidStudio2.3` and `/root/.android` (after making a backup)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has something to do with the script looking at the `root` location. Have you tried using `chown` on the unzipped content directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to install

> Download the studio
>
> Extract to home
>
> go to android-studio/bin/
>
> Mouse right click than open terminal
>
> type ./studio than press enter

now it will start to install studio. If you installing first time than It will download some files of SDK. and if you have already downloaded SDK than you can cancel download and set you SDK path from the setting from right bottom corner.

Answer (score 1):

try creating repositories.cfg -- Because I see it as warning. Let's see what happens after that!

```
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg /* Linux */
```

Comment: Didn't helped.,

Answer (score 0):

Extract your downloaded Android Studio setup zip file to your `/home/<user_name>` directory and in terminal follow the below commands

```
$ sudo chmod +x studio.sh
```

And hit enter 
Now run the following command

```
$ ./studio.sh
```

And wait for some time to download the required libraries.

Comment: The OP did exactly that.

Comment: Yeah. But I suggested that to use `/home` directory and change the file execution with `chmod` command. The OP did not try with this I guess.

Comment: There are some other answers that did not help but advised to use `chown` & the OP launched the file somehow, that means it's already an executable.

Comment: Yes, I tried both `./studio.sh` and `sh studio.sh`. These are access rights of the file `studio.sh` `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root` now.