# Installing Android Studio - Some index files failed to download

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, apt, dpkg

According to [this](https://github.com/paolorotolo/android-studio) page, I tried to install android studio as described [here](https://mfonville.github.io/android-studio/)

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
$ sudo apt-get update
```

but it failed

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found                          

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I [downloaded](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/android-studio/releases) `android-studio_4.13.0-ubuntu0_all.deb`

then

```
$ sudo dpkg -i android-studio_4.13.0-ubuntu0_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 297784 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking android-studio (from android-studio_4.13.0-ubuntu0_all.deb) ...
--2017-07-16 09:49:55--  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.5.0.4/android-studio-ide-141.2422023-linux.zip
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.201.110, 2a00:1450:4014:801::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.201.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-16 09:49:55 ERROR 404: Not Found.

dpkg: error processing android-studio_4.13.0-ubuntu0_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 8
Errors were encountered while processing:
 android-studio_4.13.0-ubuntu0_all.deb
```

Comment: Try downloading Android Studio from [official](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) website. It's easy to install just extract the file and run `studio.sh` from the command line. This will launch the installation wizard.

Comment: I'm trying this way, because I have stuck with official solution [already second bounty and not solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858582/android-studio-2-3-3-stucks-when-first-run)

Comment: I checked that git repository. It's very old. The current version of Android Studio version is 2.3.3.  Even I also using Ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine. Don't try with that repository solution it's very old